# jQuery UI show/hide with slide left not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui

I'm trying to get a menu to slide in/out using jQuery UI and I can't seem to get it to work in any version of Internet Explorer.

I'm using some conditionals to slightly modify the code for IE, but its only the difference between a "hover" event and a "click". Its working flawlessly in every other browser but breaks in IE.

You can see the site itself at: http://actionfreightinc.kemdev.com/

I'm trying to modify that menu that shows up on the left side of the rotating images.

Its worth noting that when I tried stripping out the various elements, it appeared to start working when I removed the LI items and just left the links.

Thanks all!

Here's all my various code...

Javascript (for IE):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#arrow').click(function(){
        jQuery(this).hide('slide',{direction:'left'},200, function() {
            jQuery('.menu-main-container').show('slide',{direction:'left'},500);
            jQuery('.menu-main-container li a').show();
        });
    });
jQuery('.menu-main-container').mouseleave(function(){
    jQuery('.menu-main-container').hide('slide',{direction:'left'},500, function(){
        jQuery('#arrow').show('slide',{direction:'left'},200);
        });
    });
});
```

And here's the HTML its trying to act on (stripped down to just one LI):

```
<div id="home-nav">
    <div id="arrow" style="display: block; ">
        <img src="http://actionfreightinc.kemdev.com/wp-content/themes/thesis_18/custom/images/menu2.png" alt="Menu">
    </div>
    <div class="menu-main-container" style="display: none; ">
<ul id="menu-main" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-5" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-5"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
</ul></div>                
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS (theres some other rules being applied from other areas, but this is the gist of it):

```
        .custom #home-nav {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
        position: absolute;
        left: 10px;
        top: 50px;
        z-index: 600;
    }

    .home .menu-main-container {
        background: transparent url(images/home-nav-bgd.png) no-repeat right bottom;
        margin: 0;
        display: none;
        width: 200px;
        /*float: left;*/
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-top: 0;
        z-index: 601;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;

    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;

    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;

    behavior: url(PIE/PIE.htc);
    }
    .home .menu-main-container #menu-main {
        background: transparent url(images/home-nav-bgd.png) no-repeat right top;
        padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
        margin: 0;
        width: 160px;
        z-index: 602;
    }
    .home .menu-main-container #menu-main a {
        width: 140px;
        font-size: 1.6em;
    }

    .home #arrow {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        background: none;
        width: 38px;
        height: 255px;
        display: block;
        padding: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .custom #home-nav .sub-menu {
        left: 140px;
        top: 0;
        background: #FFF;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 140px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #000000;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;

    behavior: url(PIE/PIE.htc);
    }
    .custom #home-nav #menu-main .sub-menu li a {
        width: 140px;
    }
```

Comment: depending on what version of IE you're looking at, Hover only works on <a> and not <li> or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at layout tab in console. Main Menu container has 0 height and 0 width. All that you are seeing is overflow. Dimensioning will likely help

Comment: That was it! I added some `clear` properties to the UL and LI items and now its working. Thanks a bunch!